# HTML5 video causes fixed div to stick

Tags: css, html, position, html5-video, fixed

I have a html5 video placed in a div at the top of my page. I've also put a fixed position header above it, the only problem is when the page is scrolled the header starts to stick in places. It snaps back to its proper position. Ive tried the page without the video and it has no problem.

Comment: can you show your code or a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something isn't updating fast enough. That's why I don't trust web code :).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this problem by removing the negative z-index on the div containing the video. Putting positive z-index on the content and nav made them slide over the top and not stick. Not sure how this fixed it but it works!